# file handling and threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to read three files using thread and then pass on the content to the writer class to write it to another file. The thread associated with the first file(which has line break in it) is returning back after every line break. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening. I will be pasting my code of the reader class.

```
package filehandling;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReading extends Thread{
    BufferedReader fis;
    int count=0;
    FileWriting fw;
    String str1, str2;
     String ssr;
    public FileReading(String str) throws IOException
    {

        //getting filename
        File f= new File(str);
        String strin;
        strin= f.getName();
        System.out.println(".." + strin);

        //splitting filename to get the initial name
        String stra[]= new String[2];

         stra= strin.split("\\.");
         str1= stra[0];
         str2= stra[1];

        System.out.println("extension name :" + str2);
        System.out.println("filename :" + str1);


        //associating file to input stream
        fis= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    }

     public void run()
       {


           try
           {
    while((ssr=fis.readLine())!=null)
               {
                   //file contents
                   System.out.println(ssr);

                   //writer thread
                   fw= new FileWriting(str1,ssr);
                   fw.start();

                   //assigning thread time to read,else next thread comes in
                   join(1000);
               }
           }

           catch(Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println("exception : " + e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace());
           }

       }
}
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "returning back".

Comment: Starting a new thread for every line makes no sense; calling `join` makes no sense either— so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Holger i am passing three files with three threads, reading them one by one and if a thread takes longer time, the thread goes into waiting state,the other reads thread reads its file and so on....now when i am reading i have started a writer thread and is passing the lines read in that time period to the writer. The join() is making the other threads wait for that amount of time.

Comment: “The join() is making the other threads wait for that amount of time.” How did you come to that strange idea? You should read the documentation of the methods to get what they do.

Comment: @Holger....the join is making the current thread die after the specified time....or it makes the other thread wait until the current thread dies. But it is dependent on the OS for the timing...so it might show some unexpected behavior. Sorry for the wrong explanation of the join().

Comment: @user3007767: `join` does *not* make the current thread die. It will only *wait* for a thread to die, whereas “die” means just reaching its end, there’s no enforcement. The current thread will be the one to wait and the thread on which you invoke the method is the thread which ought to die. But in your code, the waiting thread and the thread to die are the same. So the thread will never die as it is currently waiting for itself to die. Since you have specified a timeout you have effectively abused the `join` method as a `sleep` method. The other threads of your application are not affected.

Comment: @Holger....thanks buddy!! it is more clearer now.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sense in starting multiple threads within the process of reading a single file. Reading from a file data stream has no opportunity for parallel execution. But you can read three independent files in parallel by using three threads using an ordinary loop within each thread.

There is another misconception; you seem to think that you have to assign time to the threads. That’s wrong, you don’t need to think about that and you can’t do it the way you tried. When you start three threads, each of them reading and writing a file, all of them will go to sleep when no data are available and proceed on new data. The operating system will assign them CPU time appropriately.

Since you don’t have given a write part I can’t give you a code example for your task, but here is a simple example of reading three files in parallel and getting their contents back as a `String`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ReadFile implements Callable<String>
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    // enter the three file names here
    String[] file={
      "",
      "",
      ""};
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(file.length);
    List<Callable<String>> jobs=new ArrayList<>(file.length);
    for(String f:file) jobs.add(new ReadFile(f));
    List<Future<String>> all = executorService.invokeAll(jobs);
    System.out.println("all files have been read in");
    int i=0; for(Future<String> f:all) { i++;
      System.out.println("file "+i+": ");
      try
      {
        String contents = f.get();
        System.out.println(contents);
      } catch(ExecutionException ex)
      {
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  final String fileName;

  public ReadFile(String file) {
    fileName=file;
  }
  public String call() throws Exception {
    String newLine=System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    try(BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
      for(;;) {
        String line=r.readLine();
        if(line==null) break;
        sb.append(line).append(newLine);
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

The line `executorService.invokeAll` will invoke the `call` methods of all provided `ReadFile` instances, each of them in another `Thread`. These threads read their files in a loop, becoming blocked whenever the I/O system has no new data for them, giving the other threads a chance to proceed. However, don’t expect three threads to run significantly faster the one thread processing the files one after another. The limiting factor is the I/O speed of your harddrive/SSD/etc. You have the most chances of getting more speed by multiple threads when all files lie on different devices.

Things will look different if the threads are not just reading or writing but also performing some computations.

Comment: @holger....quite a help man..!! thanks..!! i have to read and write the text to another file. can this be done without using threads??

Comment: Of course, you can simply read a line inside the loop and write it to the writer inside the same loop. But if you just want to copy the files without any text processing nor changing the character encoding, you don’t need to deal with Readers and Writers or lines at all. You can just copy from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` in terms of `byte`s using a byte array buffer. The same can be achieved even easier (and more efficient at the same time): just create a `FileChannel` for the input and another for the output and use `inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel)`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long, long, java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)